# What is the word, if any, for the missing liquid in an unopened bottle?

Tags: word-usage, definition

I have a question: Is there a word for the missing liquid in an unopened bottle? If any of you can recall, bottles that contain liquid are not usually filled to the top; they have an area that isn't full, much like a bag of potato chips.  Is there a word in English for this?  I think there may be as I think I've heard it before, but I can't remember and just wanted to know.

Thank you for taking the time to find out.

Comment: P.S. I think I've just remembered it. It's **ullage**. Can anyone confirm that I am correct? or is this just used for lost liquid?

Comment: Please use existing tags - a tag with a single question associated with it isn't useful. There is some [information on tags](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) in the [help] and the [Death of Meta Tags blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ullage) states:

> Definition of ullage
>
> : the amount that a container (such as a tank or cask) lacks of being full

(And what clumsy definition that is.)

[Oxford online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ullage) says much the same, but expresses it better, and is broader:

> Definition of ullage in English:
>
> ullage
>
> NOUN
>
> mass noun
>
> 1      The amount by which a container falls short of being full.

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote this question, I couldn't remember the word, but it later popped into my head and I was pretty sure that I had remembered it correctly.